# How do i use GraphMLReader2 in Jung?

Tags: java, jung

I want to use class GraphMLReader to read a Undirected Graph from graphML with JUNG2.0.

The code is as follow:

```
import edu.uci.ics.jung.io.*;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.io.graphml.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.commons.collections15.Transformer;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.*;

class Vertex{
        int id;
        String type;
        String value;
}

class Edge{
        int id ;
        String type;
        String value;
}

public class Loader{
        static String src = "test.xsl";

        public static void  Main( String[] args){
                Reader reader = new FileReader(src );
                Transformer<NodeMetadata, Vertex> vtrans = new Transformer<NodeMetadata,Vertex>(){
                        public Vertex transform(NodeMetadata nmd ){
                                Vertex v = new Vertex() ;
                                v.type = nmd.getProperty("type");
                                v.value = nmd.getProperty("value");
                                v.id = Integer.valueOf( nmd.getId() );
                                return v;
                        }
                };
                Transformer<EdgeMetadata, Edge> etrans = new Transformer<EdgeMetadata,Edge>(){
                        public Edge transform( EdgeMetadata emd ){
                                Edge e = new Edge() ;
                                e.type = emd.getProperty("type");
                                e.value = emd.getProperty("value");
                                e.id = Integer.valueOf( emd.getId() );
                                return e;
                        }
                };
                Transformer<HyperEdgeMetadata, Edge> hetrans = new Transformer<HyperEdgeMetadata,Edge>(){

                        public Edge transform( HyperEdgeMetadata emd ){
                                Edge e = new Edge() ;
                                e.type = emd.getProperty("type");
                                e.value = emd.getProperty("value");
                                e.id = Integer.valueOf( emd.getId() );
                                return e;
                        }
                };
                Transformer< GraphMetadata , UndirectedSparseGraph> gtrans = new Transformer<GraphMetadata,UndirectedSparseGraph>(){
                        public UndirectedSparseGraph<Vertex,Edge> transform( GraphMetadata gmd ){
                                return new UndirectedSparseGraph<Vertex,Edge>();
                        }
                };



                GraphMLReader2< UndirectedSparseGraph<Vertex,Edge> , Vertex , Edge> gmlr =
                        new GraphMLReader2< UndirectedSparseGraph<Vertex,Edge> ,Vertex, Edge>(
                                        reader,
                                        gtrans,
                                        vtrans,
                                        etrans,
                                        hetrans);
                UndirectedSparseGraph<Vertex,Edge> g = gmlr.readGraph();

                return ;

        }
}
```

However, compiler alert that:

```
    Loader.java:60: cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor GraphMLReader2(java.io.Reader,org.apache.commons.collections15.Transformer<edu.uci.ics.jung.io.graphml.GraphMetadata,edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.UndirectedSparseGraph>,org.apache.commons.collections15.Transformer<edu.uci.ics.jung.io.graphml.NodeMetadata,Vertex>,org.apache.commons.collections15.Transformer<edu.uci.ics.jung.io.graphml.EdgeMetadata,Edge>)
location: class edu.uci.ics.jung.io.graphml.GraphMLReader2<edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.UndirectedSparseGraph<Vertex,Edge>,Vertex,Edge>
   new GraphMLReader2< UndirectedSparseGraph<Vertex,Edge> ,Vertex, Edge>(
   ^
1 error
```

How can i solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your graph transformer declaration, you'll need to include the vertex and edge types in angle brackets too. Like this:

```
Transformer< GraphMetadata , UndirectedSparseGraph<Vertex, Edge> > gtrans
```